# I am in a Intro to Java Programming class this semester in school. I am wanting to further my knowledge in the field

Tags: java, computer-science

I have used http://www.codecademy.com in the past to learn other programs. However, codeacademy does not provide a Java tutorial. Does anyone know another website out there that could further my knowledge in the Java field?

Thanks

Comment: javapapers.com..... tutorialspoint.com etc...

Comment: search google and you will find tons of sites.This type of questions is not acceptable in stackoverflow

Comment: What you need to do is google like i did ,https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Java+tutorials&oq=Java+tutorials&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6010j0j9&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Have you tried https://www.google.com/ ?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something to really further your knowledge here is a book that I used to study and practice JAVA.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gxcpyl686r8fg5r/Prentice.Hall.Introduction.to.Java.Programming.Comprehensive.8th.Edition.Jan.2010.pdf

It's a pretty good book in my opinion and I would consider reading the book in its entirety. Coding competition sites like http://codechef.com are good places to build up your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

> Read from Headfirst Java 2nd edition, best book for Java beginners.
>   For Online study, go to: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/